# pattern for sending server side events to a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, event-handling

I am wondering if there are any design patterns that allow server side events to be passed to a website?

The best I can think of is having some state on the server that is updated when the event is triggered, then maybe call back to the server via ajax every so often to check the state, and return what I need. Is this suitable? Is there a better way of doing this?

My application is written in ASP.NET MVC4.

Comment: Take a look at signalr, it's designed to do just what you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of handling this depending on how you would like to tackle it and what technologies you would like to introduce to your stack.

Firstly, a periodic ajax call to a controller method on your server that will report the current state of the server is perfectly fine, for example: If a long running task is started on your server, returning some kind of indication of its progress via a controller method and polling that method periodically is perfectly reasonable.

The other method is to use a technology called SignalR, which essentially allows your server to call javascript functions on your client, I would certainly recommend looking into it.

Small example:

Server:

```
  public class Chat : Hub 
  {
       public void Send(string message)
      {
          // Call the addMessage method on all clients            
          Clients.All.addMessage(message);
      }
  }
```

Client:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--  If this is an MVC project then use the following -->
<!--  <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly          
        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
        chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        };

        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            // Call the chat method on the server
            chat.server.send($('#msg').val());
        });

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="msg" />
<input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />

<ul id="messages">
</ul>
  </div>
```

The above example was taken from here:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs

The SignalR website can be found here:
http://signalr.net/

I really love SignalR... it will probably provide the best experience for both you the programmer and the user too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be looking at the [SignalR Project](http://signalr.net/). This allows bi directional server communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for server event using long polling/comet it mean that you should send ajax request to server and ajax request not executed at once, request will wait for server event until timeout expired.

Alternatively you can to listening server's events using ajax call server events like this, without signalR framework, for example:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        static readonly ManualResetEvent Starter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public String RiseServerEvent()
        {
            Starter.Set();
            return "";
        }

        public async Task<String> WaitForServerEvent()
        {
            string contents = null;
            var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var reg = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject
                             (Starter, (state, @out) =>
                             {
                                 contents = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                             }, "Some Data", -1, true);

                Starter.WaitOne(10000);   
                contents = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
            });
            await result;
            return contents;
        }

    }
```